# Unity Custom Inspector List<SerializableObject> is not saving values when scene is changed (or unity is closed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm trying to create a custom inspector for one of my classes in Unity:

my main class looks like this:

```
public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{


    public int width;
    public int height;

    [SerializeField]
    public List<Tile> tiles;
}
```

my Tile class looks like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Tile  {

    public TileType tileType;
    public Sprite tileTexture;
}
```

And this is my Editor class:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MapGenerator))]
public class MapGeneratorEditor : Editor
{

    static bool showMapProperties = true;
    static bool showTiles = true;
    private SerializedObject _target;
    SerializedProperty _mTiles;
    int _mTilesSize;
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        MapGenerator myTarget = (MapGenerator)target;
        SerializedObject _mySerializedTarget = new SerializedObject(target);

        _mySerializedTarget.Update();
        _mySerializedTarget.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        //SerializedProperty _mySerializedTileList = _mySerializedTarget.FindProperty("tiles");

        showMapProperties = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showMapProperties, new GUIContent("Map Properties", "Set different properties fot the map generation."));

        if (showMapProperties)
        {
            myTarget.width = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(new GUIContent("Width", "Specify the width of the map"), myTarget.width, 1, 100);
            myTarget.height = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(new GUIContent("Height", "Specify the height of the map"), myTarget.height, 1, 100);
        }

        showTiles = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showTiles, new GUIContent("Tiles List", "Tiles that are used to generate the map"));


        if (showTiles)
        {

            _mTilesSize = myTarget.tiles.Count;


            for (int y = 0; y < _mTilesSize; y++)
            {
                myTarget.tiles[y].tileType = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Tile Type", myTarget.tiles[y].tileType);
                myTarget.tiles[y].tileTexture = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(new GUIContent("Walkable Tile", "Tile where the enemies can walk"), myTarget.tiles[y].tileTexture, typeof(Sprite), false, null);
                GUILayout.Label("____________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
            }


            if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Add new Tile", "Click to add a new tile to the list")))
            {
                Tile newTile = new Tile();
                newTile.tileType = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Tile Type", TileType.NONE);
                //newTile.tileType = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(new GUIContent("Tile Type", "Type of selected tile"), newTile.tileType,GUIStyle.none,null);
                newTile.tileTexture = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(new GUIContent("Tile Texture", "Tile Texture"), newTile.tileTexture, typeof(Sprite), false, null);
                //tiles.Add(newTile);
                myTarget.tiles.Add(newTile);

            }

            if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Remove Tile", "Click to remove the last tile in the list")))
            {
                //myTarget.Invoke("RemoveTile", 0.0f);
                //if (tiles.Count > 0)
                //    tiles.RemoveAt(tiles.Count - 1);

                if (myTarget.tiles.Count > 0)
                    myTarget.tiles.RemoveAt(myTarget.tiles.Count - 1);
            }

            if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Remove All Tile", "Click to remove all tiles in the list")))
            {
                myTarget.tiles.Clear();
            }

        }

        if (GUI.changed)
        {
            Debug.Log("GUI Changed");
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
        }
        _mySerializedTarget.Update();
        _mySerializedTarget.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
```

It looks like this in my editor:
[image]

My problem is that if I change any property of the Tiles List, meaning if I modify a enum or add a texture to one of the variables the value or texture assigned is removed once I change the scene or if Unity is closed.

This is the very first time that I tried something like this in the editor. any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't feel right to me, to have static members in the editor.

You should try to get every data from the object you want to manage with the editor.

Comment: The static values are only used to know if the "Map Properties" or "Tiles List" is folded or unfolded. they are not related to any variable in the Behaviour script.

Comment: There is a static list. I meant this member, not the booleans, those seem fine to me.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to delete that variable, is actually not being used in the script. I have created it when I was testing different ways to display the editor.

Comment: I just copied the whole scripts and I have no problems at all.
The only thing I changed was: I added a `= new List<Tile>();` to your MapGenerator-class.

Comment: that didn't work for me. I was able to "save" only the first element of the List after clicking on "Reset Component" and adding a new element to the list... after doing that I noticed that when I wanted to change scene Unity ask me if I want to save and it works... but when I go back and add a second element to the list Unity does not asked me to save my changes on the scene, that was the real problem. Unity didn't recognized my changes... so I forced them and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the problem was that Unity was not recognizing the changes on the scene so I have forced them using

EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene());

I found that behaviour after clicking on "Reset Component" then clicking on my button "Add new Tile" , the new tile is added successfully then I tried to change the scene and unity asked to save the scene, I clicked on "OK" and when I returned to the scene everything was fine, so I tried adding a new Tile, the new tile is added but when I changed the scene Unity didn't asked to save changes.

now my MapGeneratorEditor.cs script looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MapGenerator))]
public class MapGeneratorEditor : Editor
{

    static bool showMapProperties = true;
    static bool showTiles = true;
    private SerializedObject _target;
    SerializedProperty _mTiles;
    int _mTilesSize;
    MapGenerator myTarget;


    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {

        myTarget = (MapGenerator)target;

        //SerializedProperty _mySerializedTileList = _mySerializedTarget.FindProperty("tiles");

        showMapProperties = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showMapProperties, new GUIContent("Map Properties", "Set different properties fot the map generation."));

        if (showMapProperties)
        {
            myTarget.width = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(new GUIContent("Width", "Specify the width of the map"), myTarget.width, 1, 100);
            myTarget.height = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(new GUIContent("Height", "Specify the height of the map"), myTarget.height, 1, 100);
        }

        showTiles = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showTiles, new GUIContent("Tiles List", "Tiles that are used to generate the map"));


        if (showTiles)
        {

            _mTilesSize = myTarget.tiles.Count;


            for (int y = 0; y < _mTilesSize; y++)
            {
                myTarget.tiles[y].tileType = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Tile Type", myTarget.tiles[y].tileType);
                myTarget.tiles[y].tileTexture = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(new GUIContent("Tile Texture", "Tile Texture"), myTarget.tiles[y].tileTexture, typeof(Sprite), false, null);

                GUILayout.Label("____________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
            }


            if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Add new Tile", "Click to add a new tile to the list")))
            {
                Tile newTile = new Tile();
                newTile.tileType = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Tile Type", TileType.NONE);
                //newTile.tileType = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(new GUIContent("Tile Type", "Type of selected tile"), newTile.tileType,GUIStyle.none,null);
                newTile.tileTexture = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(new GUIContent("Tile Texture", "Tile Texture"), newTile.tileTexture, typeof(Sprite), false, null);
                //tiles.Add(newTile);
                myTarget.tiles.Add(newTile);

            }

            if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Remove Tile", "Click to remove the last tile in the list")))
            {
                //myTarget.Invoke("RemoveTile", 0.0f);
                //if (tiles.Count > 0)
                //    tiles.RemoveAt(tiles.Count - 1);

                if (myTarget.tiles.Count > 0)
                    myTarget.tiles.RemoveAt(myTarget.tiles.Count - 1);
            }

            if (GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("Remove All Tiles", "Click to remove all tiles in the list")))
            {
                myTarget.tiles.Clear();
            }

        }

        if(GUI.changed)
            EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene());


    }


}
```

Comment: `MarkSceneDirty` seems to be the best way to handle your problem after all I've read from you. I always tend to press [Ctrl]+[S] after everything I do, so I didn't notice!